# Send query from bash to sqlplus

Tags: oracle, bash, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I have a bash script that has to connect to sqlplus and execute a query or procedure

How can I do that?

This doesn't work..

```
  function log_to_sqlplus() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ] && [ "$2" != "" ];
    then
        sqlplus '$1/$2' <<EOF 
        BEGIN
              DBTEST.SP_RUN();
         END; /
EOF
    fi
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - what happens? Is that exactly what you're trying to run or have you changed the formatting for posting?

Comment: @AlexPoole check now please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have the credentials enclosed in single quotes, that will prevent log on succeeding even if the arguments appear correct. (I'd suggest you probably also want to use the -s and -l flags).

You also need the slash (`/`) to be on a line on its own, and it's usually shown at the start of the line though it doesn't seem to matter here:

```
function log_to_sqlplus() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ] && [ "$2" != "" ];
    then
        sqlplus -s -l $1/$2 <<EOF 
        BEGIN
            DBTEST.SP_RUN();
        END;
        /
EOF
    fi
}
```

Tested running a procedure I have access to:

```
#!/bin/bash

function log_to_sqlplus() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ] && [ "$2" != "" ];
    then
        sqlplus -l -s $1/$2 <<EOF
        BEGIN
            -- DBTEST.SP_RUN();
            dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(user);
        END;
        /
EOF
    fi
}

log_to_sqlplus my_username my_password
```

which got output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```